# How to manage a clogged chimney problem in a rocket mass heater?

Tags: heating, fireplace, biomass

I see some designs for [rocket mass heaters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rocket_mass_heater) on the internet and I found them very interesting as a sustainable heat source.

In a normal wood-burning fireplace, the chimney needs frequently cleaning. But in a rocket mass heater, the outlet pipe has several bends, so **how can we avoid blocking the chimney outlet and how can we keep it clean?**

Comment: can you include a picture/schematic that shows the bends you are mentioning?

Comment: Also, when skimming the pics. in the rich soil article, I did not see any way to add secondary air. Are you sure this is a well thought design and are you sure the issue you mention is actually adressed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chimneys almost never **clog** from soot/creosote buildup, so your assumption is flawed, but thick buildup is dangerous because of the potential chimney fire.

A well-designed, well-managed rocket mass heater will produce a tiny fraction of the buildup of a conventional woodstove. So the concern is minimized.

You can build a cleanout at each corner to let you reach in with cleaning tools.

Comment: Just adding some info to what JB said, Rocket Mass heaters raise the combustion temperature higher than a regular fireplace causing greater separation of volatile compounds (more fuel actually burns).  Additionally, most increase the air/fuel ratio lean of stoichiometric significantly reducing particulate condensation.  The result is a, "rocket mass heater will produce a tiny fraction of the buildup of a conventional woodstove".